# Modifying electrical boxes with field mounting and knockout provisions

Tags: electrical, wiring

I had to replace an entire coax run and noticed that someone who installed my Aunt's TV put a outlet behind the TV and used a low-voltage box! I know why they did this, mostly because there is only 1" clearance to the cement that is behind the drywall (perimeter wall) and they were lazy.

I already "corrected" the problem but I wanted to know if what I did is ok.

I found the smallest Carlon blue box that Home Depot carries and drilled a 1/2" hole in the bottom and put a romex clamp in to hold the romex (for various reasons I couldn't use the side clamps that come with the box). I then secured the box to the cement using a screw through the back of the box and covered the screw with electrical tape (read something about doing that with screws inside a box that aren't electrical in nature).

Is there anything against modifying the box in the way I did?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### As long as the box is rigidly secured, you're good to go regarding the box mounting arrangement

Considering that the concrete wall can be considered to be a structural member, not an exposed building surface, and that the box is mounted independently of the finished building surface, NEC 314.23(B)(1) applies here, which permits the field-drilled mounting hole and screw arrangement used provided it secures the box sufficiently and the AHJ is OK with it upon inspection:

> **(B) Structural Mounting.** An enclosure supported from a
>   structural member or from grade shall be rigidly supported
>   either directly or by using a metal, polymeric, or wood brace.
>
> **(1) Nails and Screws.** Nails and screws, where used as a fastening means, shall secure boxes by using brackets on the outside
>   of the enclosure, or by using mounting holes in the back or in
>   a single side of the enclosure, or they shall pass through the
>   interior within 6 mm (1∕4 in.) of the back or ends of the enclosure. Screws shall not be permitted to pass through the box
>   unless exposed threads in the box are protected using
>   approved means to avoid abrasion of conductor insulation.
>   Mounting holes made in the field shall be approved.

### Field KOs in a box should be OK as well

Making knockouts (whether of standard or nonstandard size) in electrical boxes in the field is a long-standing practice in the electrical industry (in fact, some enclosures ship without knockouts, expecting the user to make their own).  As far as I can tell, as long as the cable is adequately secured to the box with a standard cable clamp (as per 314.17(C)), it makes no difference whether the KO is factory or field made.

### However, a box that shallow doesn't have enough fill for...much of anything

The shallowest Carlon nonmetallic boxes (at 1.25" deep), while technically deep enough for a receptacle (at only 0.69" for the receptacle + the minimum 1/4" of extra depth required by Code), do not provide enough *box fill* at 8in3 to accommodate a hot, a neutral, a ground, an allowance for a cable clamp, and the double allowance for the receptacle yoke -- for 14AWG wire, this would require 12in3 of fill.  As a result, you'll need to slap a 5/8" deep non-metallic single gang box extender (or construct one using a 1/4" and a 3/8" stacked atop each other) on there to gain that extra couple of cubic inches of fill.

Comment: Great to hear about the first few points. The last point I think is interesting; tbh I don't feel concerned about it as I feel nothing was too cramped and made sure everything was properly isolated. Extender would protrude past drywall. With that being said, I checked the other boxes that were installed when the addition was made and they are metal, mounted to the concrete, are daisy chained (2 14/2 goes in) and the same depth. This addition passed inspections so I assume either a) the inspector didn't care to much about it b) metal boxes have different fill requirements?

Comment: I should note: had I done this entire install I probably would have done surface mount. Also the low-voltage outlet box was done *after* the addition (presumably by some handyman special).

Comment: @Alex -- different box types/dimensions have different volumes, yes, and it's OK for the extenders to protrude past the drywall :)

Comment: I have field modified these boxes and passed inspection, some inspectors question this but I have not been red tagged. As far as box fill I have usually installed a junction box in the top of the wall at the ceiling because these shallow boxes don't have the cubic inches for anything but 1 cable as 3 phase pointed out.+